# Ayuda con numero de arreglo en C

Tags: c, array, optimización

Estoy intentando hacer el siguiente programa con uso de arreglo unidimensional:

Crea un arreglo de tipo entero, pregunta al usuario cuántos valores enteros  va a capturar, esa cantidad será la longitud del arreglo. Tener un menú con las siguientes opciones:

1. Capturar valores
2. Ordenar valores
3. imprimir valores originales
4. imprimir valores ordenados
5. Salir

El código que tengo es el siguiente, pero, ¿Cómo hacer que el usuario ingrese la cantidad de *arrays* que quiere?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAMANIO 15 /*define los tamaños de los arreglos*/

void procesa( int resp[] ); /*prototipo de funcion*/
void ordena_arreglo( int a[] ); /*prototipo de funcion*/
void imprime_arreglo( const int a[] ); /*prototipo de funcion*/

int main(){/*la función main comienza la ejecución del programa*/
    int respuesta[TAMANIO];
    int i, total=0;

    printf("\n\tPrograma que almacena en arreglos digitos para despues ser ordenados\n\n\n");

    printf("Ingrese los 15 numeros enteros:\n");
    for( i=0; i < TAMANIO; i++ ){
        printf("\n\t\t\tIntroduzca valor [%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &respuesta[i]);
    }/*fin de for*/

    procesa( respuesta );/*fución qu procesa las respuestas*/

    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}/*fin de la función main*/

void procesa( int resp[] ){/*ordena el arreglo e imprime por pantalla*/
    printf("\n\nEl arreglo llamado respuestas desordenado es: \n");
    imprime_arreglo( resp );/*muestra el arreglo desordenado*/

    ordena_arreglo( resp );/*ordena el arreglo*/

    printf("\n\n\nEl arreglo llamado respuesta ordenado es: \n");
    imprime_arreglo( resp );/*muestra el arreglo ordenado*/
}/*fin de la función procesa*/

void ordena_arreglo( int a[] ){/*función que ordena un arreglo*/
    int pasada; /*contador de pasadas*/
    int j; /*contaodr de pasadas*/
    int almacena;/*ubicación temporal utilizada para intercambiar los elementos*/

    for ( pasada = 1; pasada < TAMANIO; pasada++ ){/*ciclo para controlar el número de pasadas*/
        for ( j = 0; j < TAMANIO - 1; j++ ){/*ciclo para controlar el número de comparaciones por pasada*/
            if ( a[ j ] > a[ j + 1 ] ){/*intercambia los elementos si no se encuentran en orden*/
                almacena = a[ j ];
                a[ j ] = a[ j + 1 ];
                a[ j + 1 ] = almacena;
            }/*fin de if*/
        }/*fin del for interno*/
    }/*fin del for externo*/
}/*fin de la función ordena_arreglo*/

void imprime_arreglo( const int a[] ){/*muestra el contenido del arreglo (5 valores por línea)*/
    int j; /* contador */

    for ( j = 0; j < TAMANIO; j++ ){/*muestra el contenido del arreglo*/
        if ( j % 5 == 0 ){/* comienza una nueva línea cada 5 valores*/
            printf( "\n" );
        }/*fin de ifend if*/
        printf( "%3d", a[ j ] );
    }/*fin de for*/
} /* fin de la función imprime_arreglo */
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar memoria dinámica. Te recomiendo que investigues sobre el funcionamiento de la función malloc ()

La memoria dinámica se utiliza cuando el tamaño de memoria requerido por un programa puede variar luego de que haya comenzado su ejecución y eso es justamente tu caso.

Si el usuario quisiera un arreglo de 1000 posiciones ocuparía un espacio en memoria completamente distinto que si quisiera 15, es por eso que necesitas forzosamente pedir memoria durante la ejecución del programa y por eso debes utilizar malloc

```
int tamanio;
int * comienzo;

printf ("Ingresé tamaño de array");
scanf ("%d",&tamanio);

comienzo = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int)*tamanio);
```

En ese pequeño ejemplo comienzo sería la dirección de memoria donde empieza tu arreglo y deberías poder utilizarlo para manipular el array.

Comment: En este [site](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html) hay una muy buena explicación

Comment: Ahí hice una edición agregando un pequeño ejemplo sobre como deberías usar malloc, pero igualmente no dejes de informarte sobre su uso, ya que es muy importante y lo usaras mucho en el futuro si sigues programando en C